# How to connect to different DB process from JDBC DataSource

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, database-connection, apache-camel

I'm writing Java application with Apache Camel and use JDBC DataSource(Apache commons DBCP).

I can create many connections but all connections are handled in one Oracle client process, what I may see in sessions table `select * from v$session`.

The question is how to connect from one Java application to different Oracle processes to improve performance? If you know a way to do it using other Java technologies, not used in my example, it is also very interesting.

```
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Main main = new Main();
    String url = "some url";
    String user = "user";
    String password = "password";
    DataSource dataSource = setupDataSource(url, user, password);

    // bind dataSource into the registery
    main.bind("oraDataSource", dataSource);
    main.enableHangupSupport();
    main.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());
    main.run(args);

}

private static DataSource setupDataSource(String connectURI, String user, String password) {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    ds.setMaxActive(20);
    LOG.info("max active conn: " + ds.getMaxActive());
    ds.setUsername(user);
    ds.setPassword(password);
    ds.setUrl(connectURI);
    return ds;
}

public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

Processor logProcessor = new LogProcessor();
Processor createAnswer = new CreateAnswerProc();
Processor dbPaymentProcessor = new DbPaymentQueryProcessor();

/**
 * Let's configure the Camel routing rules using Java code...
 */
public void configure() {

    from("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/ps.vin_test_send?exchangeType=topic&autoDelete=false&queue=ps.test_send_queue&concurrentConsumers=20&threadPoolSize=20")
            .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Payment[].class)
            .process(dbPaymentProcessor)
            .to("jdbc:oraDataSource")
            .process(logProcessor)
            .process(createAnswer)
            .to("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/ps.vin_test?username=test&password=test&exchangeType=topic&autoDelete=false&routingKey=ps.vin_test_key&queue=vin_test_queue&concurrentConsumers=20");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the way for oracle is to change db propeties from dedicated to shared. And it will share processes between users. but it is not recomended and not give any performance.

Creation of multiple datasources only reduces performance.